# Efficiently loop through an object based on an array of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am getting the users navigation "state" in a mobile navigation as an Array. For example:

```
['3124', '5312', '5232']
```

I need to use that state, to grab the Object that has the ID of `'5232'`, 3 levels down in the object.

The Array length can differ, meaning it can return between 1 and 5 ids, so I don't always have to loop all the way down.

This is what the data for the navigation can look like, using the same IDs as I used in the example above, I would like my function to return the "evening" object with ID `'5232'`:

```
[
    { 
        id: "3124", 
        name: "women", 
        children: [
            {
                id: "5312",
                name: "dresses",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "8399",
                        name: "wedding",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: "5232",
                        name: "evening",
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "3291",
                name: "shoes",
                children: []
            }
        ] 
    },
    { 
        id: "9482", 
        name: "men", 
        children: [
            {
                id: "8292",
                name: "jackets",
                children: []
            },
            {
                id: "3829",
                name: "hats",
                children: []
            }
        ] 
    }
]
```

I've been talking this through with a couple of colleagues and we can't really figure out a good way to do this efficiently. We cannot change the data, but we can probably change how the user state is saved, if that is wrong.

I could really use some input and ideas on how to solve this problem in a good way.

Comment: so you want the object with `id: '5232'` for example?

Comment: exactly, I want to write a function that returns:


`{
  id: "5232",
  name: "evening",
  children: []
}
`

Comment: and you have the array with the path the node?

Comment: Are the ids unique throughout the whole data set? In that case, you could “flatten” the whole thing, and make it an object instead of an array, using the id as the key ... that should make look-ups fast & easy. (The nesting of your original structure could be expressed by storing the ids of the parent and children into additional fields then. Whether that’s an appropriate solution, or could pose trouble in other places, depends on what else you do with this data of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing a basic nested for loop if focusing solely on efficiency. I chose the variable name `breadcrumb` since the concept seems similar to [its role in site navigation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/breadcrumb/).

```js
function getState(breadcrumb, state) {
  let states = state;

  for (let id of breadcrumb) {
    for (state of states) {
      // found -- continue to next level
      if (state.id === id) {
        states = state.children;
        break;
      }
    }

    // not found
    if (state.id !== id) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  return state;
}

let state = [{ id: "3124", name: "women", children: [{ id: "5312", name: "dresses", children: [{ id: "8399", name: "wedding", children: [] }, { id: "5232", name: "evening", children: [] }] }, { id: "3291", name: "shoes", children: [] }] }, { id: "9482", name: "men", children: [{ id: "8292", name: "jackets", children: [] }, { id: "3829", name: "hats", children: [] }] }];
let breadcrumb = ['3124', '5312', '5232'];

console.log(getState(breadcrumb, state));
```

However, if you care more about code maintainability, I recommend a more canonical approach:

```js
function getState(breadcrumb, state) {
  return breadcrumb.reduce((state, id) => {
    return state !== null
      ? state.children.find(state => state.id === id)
      : state;
  }, { children: state });
}

let state = [{ id: "3124", name: "women", children: [{ id: "5312", name: "dresses", children: [{ id: "8399", name: "wedding", children: [] }, { id: "5232", name: "evening", children: [] }] }, { id: "3291", name: "shoes", children: [] }] }, { id: "9482", name: "men", children: [{ id: "8292", name: "jackets", children: [] }, { id: "3829", name: "hats", children: [] }] }];
let breadcrumb = ['3124', '5312', '5232'];

console.log(getState(breadcrumb, state));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function to find node by path in tree

```js
function findNodeByPath(nodes, path) {
  let node;
  
  if (!path) return;

  for (let id of path) {
    if (!nodes) break;

    for (let child of nodes) {
      if (child.id === id) {
        node = child;
        nodes = node.children;
        break;
      }
    }  
  }

  return node;
}

let nodes = [
    { 
        id: "3124", 
        name: "women", 
        children: [
            {
                id: "5312",
                name: "dresses",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "8399",
                        name: "wedding",
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: "5232",
                        name: "evening",
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "3291",
                name: "shoes",
                children: []
            }
        ] 
    },
    { 
        id: "9482", 
        name: "men", 
        children: [
            {
                id: "8292",
                name: "jackets",
                children: []
            },
            {
                id: "3829",
                name: "hats",
                children: []
            }
        ] 
    }
];

console.log(findNodeByPath(nodes, ['3124', '5312', '5232']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the arrays and take only the node of the given path id.

```js
function getObject(tree, path) {
    var temp = { children: tree };
    return path.every(p => temp = temp.children.find(({ id }) => p === id))
        ? temp
        : undefined;
}

var data = [{ id: "3124", name: "women", children: [{ id: "5312", name: "dresses", children: [{ id: "8399", name: "wedding", children: [] }, { id: "5232", name: "evening", children: [] }] }, { id: "3291", name: "shoes", children: [] }] }, { id: "9482", name: "men", children: [{ id: "8292", name: "jackets", children: [] }, { id: "3829", name: "hats", children: [] }] }],
    path = ['3124', '5312', '5232'],
    result = getObject(data, path);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using recursive function

```
   function findById(id) {
      var founded = {};

      function recurse(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i].id === id) {
            founded = data[i];
          } else if (data[i].children && data[i].children.length) {
            recurse(data[i].children);
          }
        }
      }

      recurse(catalog);
      return founded;
    };
```

some demo : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxduvzj8/1/)